# How to make rules.txt permanent in Civilization 2 Multiplayer Gold Edition?

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-2

I play Civilization 2 Multiplayer Gold Edition. I have 64 bit Windows 7. When I installed that game I also patched it with Civ2XP64Patcher.exe.

I have modified rules.txt and when I start a game the modified rules works. But when I load a game it works like it would with original rules.txt, although the file rules.txt is as it is modded.

Can someone tell me how to make the modded rules.txt permanent?